# Как организовать плавный переход между Activity по свайпу (вправо и влево)?

Tags: java, activity, swipe

Я использую Android Studio и пишу на чистом java, без всяких фреймворков и прочих дополнительных плюшек. Долго искал решение в интернете, так ничего подходящего и не нашел. Слышал про ViewPager, но он вроде не работает на чистом java. Можете подсказать еще варианты? Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит на чистом java, и какой смысл в этом?

Comment: На чистом в смысле без фреймворков и дополнений. А программирую так, потому что новичек.

Comment: Так далеко не уйдете. Используйте фрагменты и анимационный переход между ними

Comment: А можно подробнее, пожалуйста?

Comment: т.е. вы хотите программировать под android не используя компоненты android? ViewPager это если что просто один из компонентов(view) android и его использование не является "фреймворком или дополнительной плюшкой"

Comment: Согласен, спасибо. Вы поправили мое понимание всей ситуации :)